# Event Handlers not working after DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

On page load I bind Event Handlers with content which is hidden on at the time of page load.

If users clicks on the button, the hidden content is pulled and replaces the main content of the page, Now the event Handlers which were initially binded do not work.

HTML code on Page load

```
<p> Initial content of the page </p>
<button id="button"> Click Here to change content</button>
<div class="show-later" style="display: none;"> Some Hidden content </div>
```

After the user clicks a button the new dom looks some thing like this

```
<p>
 <div>Some Hidden content</div>
</p>
```

After the manipulation the event handlers binded to the div element do not work any more. Please notice that the div goes into the P element after DOM Manipulation.

jQuery Code:

```
   $('#button').click(function(){
      var show_later = $('.show-later').html();
      $('p').html(show_later);
   });

   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.show-later').click(function(){
       // Do something.....
      });
   });
```

Comment: Please show us your javascript.

Comment: Let's see the jQuery code; not entirely sure what you expect us to do without that.

Comment: how do you bind those event handler? Can you show us some code?

Comment: which version of jquery u r using? if it's 1.7.2 means use live or greater than 1.8 means use on

Comment: @muthu don't use `live`. Either use `delegate` or `bind`.

Comment: When replacing the elements, all the event handlers and associated data is no longer applicable, as the element did'nt exist when you bound the handler. You need to rebind or use delegated event handlers.

Comment: I am updating the question with jquery code.

Comment: @muthu The `.live()` function was deprecated when jQuery 1.7 was released; that's the version when all of the event binding functions were replaced by `.on()`/`.off()`. If they're using 1.7.2 they definitely should **not** be using `.live()`; even if they're using an earlier version, they should use `.bind()` (for regular events) or `.delegate()` (for delegated events) in preference to `.live()`. Unless they're using such an old version that `.delegate()` isn't a function, in which case they should probably upgrade.

Comment: When you do the `html` shuffle, you lose all bound handlers. Either use delegation, or hide the old content and unhide the new one.

Comment: @JanDvorak http://jsfiddle.net/6WtTC/1/

Comment: @AnthonyGrist http://jsfiddle.net/6WtTC/1/

Comment: @muthu Not really sure what your point is, but you seem to be confused about the definition of "delegated". The function is still in the jQuery code so *can* be used, it just *shouldn't* be used. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/): "As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`."

Comment: @muthu "deprecated" doesn't mean "doesn't work". It means "you should not use it, and we'll not support it".

Comment: thanks  JanDvorak, AnthonyGrist now i am clear

Comment: @backTangent Why are you moving the innerHtml to the 'p'-element? Why not only make the '.show-later'-element visible with $('.show-later').show() ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not moving the `<div>`, you're just taking its content (a text node) and copying that to the paragraph. Contrary to what you've stated in the question, the resulting DOM will actually look like this:

```
<p> Some Hidden content </p>
<button id="button"> Click Here to change content</button>
<div class="show-later" style="display: none;"> Some Hidden content </div>
```

The `<div>` is still there, it still has content, and it still has the event handler for `click` bound to it; but it's also still hidden, so there's no way you can click on it.

I'd suggest that you actually move the `<div>` into the `<p>` element, like so:

```
$('.show-later').show().appendTo('p');
```

That will select the `<div>`, make it visible, and then move the element itself into the `<p>`.

Comment: Oh.. I did not knew about that, what should i do to remove it?

Comment: @backTangent even if you do remove it, the event handler will not transfer to the new copy.

Comment: @backTangent I've added some more information to my answer, including some kind that should give you the result you're after.

Comment: @backTangent If you want to keep the original there, then you could use `.clone(true)` before the call to `.show()` to make a new copy of the element, and then append that to the `<p>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to change your code like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.show-later', function(){
        // Do something.....
    });
});
```

**Update2**:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var show_later = $('.show-later').html();
    $('p').html(show_later).addClass('show-later');
});
```

**Update1**: I'm not sure, what your problem exactly is. Maybe you want to make a jsfiddle-example...

The 'on'-Method registers events so that even if you remove the element a make a new one, the events is already registered.

Comment: How does it help? `click(function` is an alias to `on("click", function`.

Comment: Note that this alone won't do. Note the new content holder does not have the `show-later` class.

Comment: @JanDvorak Update: now it does.

Comment: +1 Had a similar issue to OP…setting event handlers to .on() rather than .click() (or anything else) fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
var show_later = $('.show-later').html();
$('p').html(show_later);
```

then no event handler bound to `.show-later` will become bound to the `p`. All you're doing is changing the contents of the `p`. I suggest changing the HTML as such:

```
<p class="hide-later"> Initial content of the page </p>
<p class="show-later" style="display: none;"> Some Hidden content </div>
<button id="button"> Click Here to change content</button>
```

and the javascript as such:

```
$('.show-later').show();
$('.hide-later').hide();
```

Comment: Delegation is irrelevant; he's not moving the `<div>` at all; he's just copying its content (a text node) into the `<p>` element. The `<div>` is still there with its associated `click` event handler; it's just also still not visible so can't ever be clicked on.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist you're right. Even delegated handlers will not become bound to the `p` by changing its contents.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist note that in rare cases delegated event handlers _may_ become bound to an element if its content changes. Namely, if the selector contains `:has`.

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of event delegation - to reflect changes to elements. There's still absolutely no event delegation involved here, though...